# cant get the facebook-tornado connection

Tags: facebook-graph-api, tornado

i've a problem, am a beginer and i try to make a simple asynchronous program that posts to facebook, i use the [tornado example](https://github.com/facebook/tornado/tree/master/demos/facebook) and the [tornado-facebook-sdk](https://github.com/pauloalem/tornado-facebook-sdk), here is the code:

```
class MainHandler(BaseHandler, tornado.auth.FacebookGraphMixin):
    @tornado.web.authenticated
    @tornado.web.asynchronous
    def get(self):
        self.facebook_request("/me/home", self.print_callback, access_token=self.current_user["access_token"])
        a = self.current_user["access_token"]
        #print a

    def print_callback(data):
        print data
        ioloop.stop()
        graph.get_object('/facebook', callback=print_callback)
```

and i get this error:

```
TypeError: print_callback() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

because i want to understand this example to get the token, and then use the example:

```
def callback(response):
    # ...
graph.put_object('me', 'feed', message="Maoe!!", callback=callback)
```

to write something on my facebook's wall, i did it with [the synchronous library](https://github.com/pythonforfacebook/facebook-sdk), but sadly this is blocking!

UPDATE: still getting and error:

```
class MainHandler(BaseHandler, tornado.auth.FacebookGraphMixin):
    @tornado.web.authenticated
    @tornado.web.asynchronous
    def get(self):
        self.facebook_request("/me/home", self.print_callback, access_token=self.current_user["access_token"])
        a = self.current_user["access_token"]
        print a

    def print_callback(self, data):
        graph.post_wall(self, "heloooooooo")
```

and got this error:

```
[E 121009 14:28:47 web:1108] Uncaught exception GET / (::1)
HTTPRequest(.....)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\tornado-2.4.post1-py2.7.egg\tornado\web.py", line 1043, in _stack_context_handle_exception
   raise_exc_info((type, value, traceback))
   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\tornado-2.4.post1 py2.7.egg\tornado\stack_context.py", line 237, in _nested
    yield vars
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\tornado-2.4.post1-py2.7.egg\tornado\stack_context.py", line 210, in wrapped
    callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\tornado-2.4.post1-py2.7.egg\tornado\gen.py", line 405, in inner self.set_result(key, result)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\tornado-2.4.post1-py2.7.egg\tornado\gen.py", line 335, in set_result
    self.run()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\tornado-2.4.post1-py2.7.egg\tornado\gen.py", line 365, in run
    yielded = self.gen.send(next)
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\facebook\graphapi.py", line 129, in _make_request
    raise GraphAPIError(data)
GraphAPIError: (#200) This API call requires a valid app_id.
```

and when i go to Facebook, i see that it's a valide key that i'm using, i even use the generated Token (here the `a` variable), and pasting it to Api Debug, and i got everything works fine:

```
 Valid : True
 Origin : Web
 Scopes : create_note photo_upload publish_actions publish_stream read_stream share_item status_update video_upload
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `self` to `print_callback`.

```
def print_callback(self, data):
    print data
    ioloop.stop()
    graph.get_object('/facebook', callback=print_callback)
```

Comment: so this is the famous "Explicit is better than implecit" ;)
thank you